# kubernetes dns discover fail

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes

I am new in kubernetes, I am doing lab at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

When I deploy wordpress, I always get this log:

```
│ WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...                                                                               │
│ Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html                                                                   │
│ Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22                  │
│ Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22    │
│ MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known                              │
│ Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22                  │
│ Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22    │
│ MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Although mysql pod is OK and both of them are in default namespace

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you attached, line 3, suggest that you did not specify the database connection parameters correctly in the wordpress deployment file. Please try to check the deployment configuration and see the DB host name matches with your mysql pod name which is running as it looks like the name which is present is not resolvable.

Comment: It matchs and I don't know the reason why